# Explicit locally free resolution of a perfect complex $E\oplus F\to (E\oplus F)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(D)\to (E\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(D))|_D$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories, projective-resolution

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $E,F\to X$ be 2 holomorphic vector bundles and $D\hookrightarrow X$ be a smooth divisor. Denote by $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ the line bundle associated to the divisor and let $s: \mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_X(D)$ be a section, such that $s^{-1}(0) = D$. Assume also that we have an isomorphism $E|_D\cong F|_D$ of the restrictions to $D$.

Consider the following perfect complex $\mathcal{E}^\bullet$ on $X$:
\begin{equation*}
E\oplus F\xrightarrow{
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{id}\otimes s& 0\\
0&\text{id}\otimes s
\end{pmatrix}}
 (E\oplus F)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(D)\xrightarrow{
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho_E&\rho_F
\end{pmatrix}
} (E\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(D))|_D\,,
\end{equation*}
where $\rho_{(-)}$ corresponds to restriction of sections to $D$, and we use the isomorphism $F|_D\cong E|_D$.

Now it is well known that there exists a locally free resolution of this complex on $X$. However, is it possible to write it down explicitly from what we know?

**Edit:** By a locally free resolution I mean a complex of vector bundles $L^\bullet$ with a quasi-isomorphism $L^\bullet\to \mathcal{E}^\bullet$. It is important to me that I have such a map, as I would like to use it to construct a differential operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Projections to the second summands define a morphism from that complex to the complex
$$
F \stackrel{s}\to F(D)\tag{*}
$$
of locally free sheaves. The cone of this morphism is the complex
$$
0 \to E \stackrel{s}\to E(D) \stackrel{\rho_E}\to E(D)\vert_D \to 0
$$
which is acyclic. Therefore, $(*)$ is a locally free resolution of the original complex.

EDIT. Alternatively, let 
$$
K = \mathrm{Ker}\Big((\rho_E, \rho_F) \colon E(D) \oplus F(D) \to E(D)\vert_D\Big).
$$ 
Then $K$ is locally free, the morphism $(s, s) \colon E \oplus F \to E(D) \oplus F(D)$ factors through $K$, and the complex
$$
E \oplus F \to K
$$
is quasiisomorphic to the original one (via the morphism, which is identical on $E \oplus F$ and is the natural embedding on $K$).

Comment: For me a resolutions is a complex of vector bundle $L^\bullet$ with a map $L^\bullet \to \mathcal{E}^\bullet$ which is a quasi-isomorphism. The map goes the wrong way in your case.

Comment: For me a resolution is a quasiisomorphism, no matter which direction it goes.

Comment: I have changed the question to be more explicit now. It is important to me that it goes the way that I have mentioned, otherwise it is trivial as your answer shows.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Sasha. Could you please add some argument explaining why $K$ is locally free? I am struggling to see why that is true.

Comment: Because the projective dimension of a locally free sheaf on a Cartier divisor is 1.